# How to organize JSON strings to an array clearly

Tags: javascript, json

I am now using the HTMLV feature and I want to store the information about the DOM element into a JSON file.

Thus, I create a JSON file like this:

```
var pages= 
 [  
    {
            "img_data_url": "test",
        "stamp":
        [
        {"src": "../pic/cake.png",
         "pos_x": 1,
         "pos_y": 1,
         "id_name": "stamp00"           
        },
        {"src": "../pic/egg.png",
         "pos_x": "2",
         "pos_y": "2",
         "id_name": "stamp01"
        },
        {"src": "../pic/sugar.png",
         "pos_x": "3",
         "pos_y": "3",
         "id_name": "stamp02"
        },
        {"src": "../pic/potato.png",
         "pos_x": "4",
         "pos_y": "4",
         "id_name": "stamp03"
        },
        {"src": "../pic/banana.png",
         "pos_x": "5",
         "pos_y": "5",
         "id_name": "stamp04"
        }       
        ]    
    }
    ,
    {
        "img_data_url": "test",
        "stamp":
        [
        {"src": "../pic/f.png",
         "pos_x": "1",
         "pos_y": "1",
         "id_name": "stamp10"           
        },
        {"src": "../pic/g.png",
         "pos_x": "2",
         "pos_y": "2",
         "id_name": "stamp11"
        },
        {"src": "../pic/h.png",
         "pos_x": "3",
         "pos_y": "3",
         "id_name": "stamp12"
        },
        {"src": "../pic/i.png",
         "pos_x": "4",
         "pos_y": "4",
         "id_name": "stamp13"
        },
        {"src": "../pic/j.png",
         "pos_x": "5",
         "pos_y": "5",
         "id_name": "stamp14"
        }
        ]       
    }        
]
```

I retrieve the data stored in DOM element to create each "{}" segment.

By writing:

```
var json_obj={};
json_obj["src"] = "../pic/cake.png";
json_obj["pos_x"] = 1;
json_obj["pos_y"] = 1;
json_obj["id_name"] = "stamp00";
var json_string= JSON.stringify( json_obj );
```

I got :
`"{"src":"../pic/cake.png","pos_x":1,"pos_y":1,"id_name":"stamp00"}"`

But how can I organize the data structure like this: 
`"stamp":
[]  <-- An array consists of lots of JSON strings I created above."`

Questions:

 1. Are the two double quote character (at the first and last position) " in 
`"{"src":"../pic/cake.png","pos_x":1,"pos_y":1,"id_name":"stamp00"}"`
redundant?

Why they appear? 

Would they affect my operation to retrieve the data in JSON file?

 2. I want an alternative approach instead of writing:

```
var str= "\"stamp\":[";
str += json_string;
```

to get 
    `""stamp":[{"src":"../pic/cake.png","pos_x":1,"pos_y":1,"id_name":"stamp00"}"`

Any smarter and correct approach?

Comment: Maybe you don't need JSON at all. What you say is a "JSON file" is actually a JavaScript object literal. A JSON would be a string representation of that. If your goal is `var pages= [ ... ]`, you don't need JSON.

Comment: @bfavaretto      Then what should I adopt?

Comment: Where does the data come from?

Comment: The user will create some stamp image on the canvas and I take records of these.

Comment: But how do you plan to sore them? On a database? On disk?

Comment: Store?    HTML5 new feature mentioned in the article. Local system.

Comment: So sorry, you do need JSON. The first line of code on the question confused me. You'll actually end up having something like `var pages = JSON.parse(jsonString);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mess with JSON strings directly.  Just create the structure you want and stringify that.

```
var json_obj={};
json_obj["src"] = "../pic/cake.png";
json_obj["pos_x"] = 1;
json_obj["pos_y"] = 1;
json_obj["id_name"] = "stamp00";

var json_document = {
    stamp: [ json_obj ],  // you probably want to build this array separately
};
JSON.stringify(json_document);
```

The outer quotes you're seeing are to indicate it's a JavaScript string now.  The inner quotes (which you should see escaped, with `\`?) are part of the JSON format.

Comment: Do you mean if I want to add another JSON string, I should write stamp: [json_obj , "json_obj2"]?
I want to create lots of JSON strings in the array.

Comment: you don't want JSON strings in an array.  you want _an array_, and then you want to turn it into a JSON string.  you can make an array and use `.push()` to add more items to it in a loop, if that's what you're doing.

Comment: Ok... I will try it. But is "stamp" the string and the array [] is the value.

Comment: i suggest you play around with `JSON.stringify` in your browser's console to see what it does on complicated objects.  i think you're underestimating it.

Comment: Then please wait. After I play around with the API, maybe I have some similar questions. Thus I can solve the problem, giving you the credit.